# Associating keys to JSON arrays not having keys using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, key

I have several JSON arrays. They look like

`[["Vishnu", 25],["Joginder", 22],["Amar", 27],["Rohan", 24],["Karan", 23]]`

I want to prepare a Javascript code to convert these array of arrays to JSON arrays but with keys, which looks like:

```
[{"Player": "Vishnu", "Age": 25},{"Player": "Joginder", "Age": 22},{"Player": "Amar", "Age": 27},{"Player": "Rohan", "Age": 24},{"Player": "Karan", "Age": 23}]
```

Can anyone provide me some idea, or a code for it.

Comment: you have two dimensional array - use map

Comment: @Andreas, I have edited it now, thanks. I have  replaced those square braces with the curly ones now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.map()` to return an array of objects, where first element of array is set to value of property `"Player"`, second element of array is set as value for property `"Age"`

```js
var arr = [["Vishnu", 25]
          ,["Joginder", 22]
          ,["Amar", 27]
          ,["Rohan", 24]
          ,["Karan", 23]
          ];

var res = arr.map(function(el, index) {
   return {"Player":el[0], "Age": el[1]}
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

The first array is an array of arrays(2D) array, while the new array that you intend to create need to be an array of json objects.

```
var orArray = [
  ["Vishnu", 25],
  ["Joginder", 22],
  ["Amar", 27],
  ["Rohan", 24],
  ["Karan", 23]
];

var newJsonArray = [];

// loop through the original array
orArray.forEach(function(item) {
  //check if item is an array
  if (Array.isArray(item)) {
    var _obj = {}; // Create an empty object;
    _obj.Player = item[0];// create first key;
    _obj.Age = item[1]; //Push second key
    newJsonArray.push(_obj) // Push to new array
  }
})
console.log(newJsonArray)
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/5ntesLd0/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.map()` to iterate over the players array and call a function over each element. The returned value from each iteration will create a new `Array`

```js
var players = [["Vishnu", 25],["Joginder", 22],["Amar", 27],["Rohan", 24],["Karan", 23]]

// map over the players multidimensional array
var playersObjects = players.map(function(player) {
  // inside the callback player is the current element
  // return an object with the correct properties
  return {
    Player: player[0],
    Age: player[1]
  }
})

console.log(playersObjects)
```